# Unable to stop browser navigation using $("#tag").click()

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to create a button called SignIn that accommodates browsers without javascript, but doesn't navigate when Javascript is enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#signIn").click(function () {

            //
            // Stop event bubbling
            //
            return false;
        });
    });

    // Gets the div tag and its content for an identity provider
    function GetIdentityProviderTag(idp, index)
    {
        return '<div class="identity-provider" id="button' + index + '"><button>' + idp.Name + ' </button></div>';
    }
</script>

<div>
    <a href="/NoJavascriptSignIn" id="signIn">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to permit both javascript enabled, and javascript disabled browsers to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next code snippet prevents the browser from following the link (mainly `return false`), you should remove it:

```
$(function () {
    $("#signIn").click(function () {

        //
        // Stop event bubbling
        //
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you just want to press the button automatically, use:

```
$(function () {
    $("#signIn").click();
});
```

Comment: What is different about this code that cancels navigation, then the one I posted in the question?

Comment: Nothing, it's meant to be deleted. I assumed that you want the Sign In button to be pressed automatically, but now I read your question again, it looks like you're not trying to achieve that. Your code should work, are there any errors in the error console?

Comment: Sonofagun.... my test site was in "restricted zones", but so was "internet" and "localhost".  Thanks everyone for the correct answers!

Comment: Actually more correctly stated, my internet and local host were set to "high" security.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the default action of a link click you need to add:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To your script So it will look something like

```
   $("#signIn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //
        // Code inserted here
        //
    });
```

The preventDefault() cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
<a href="/NoJavascriptSignIn" id="signIn" onclick="return signin()">Sign In</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function signin() {
    //Do sign in stuff
    return false;
}
</script>
```